# Pin an input to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I've been scratching my head over this for the last few hours. I'm trying to make an input field that stays put at the bottom of the page, similar to the Omegle chat bar.

[image: Omegle chat bar I'm referencing]

I've set my height to 100% (well, 99, because if it's set to 100 the page has unnecessary scroll bars) and set the CSS `bottom` property to `0`, but no matter what I try, the bar stays floating around 10% down the page.

My CSS code is:

```
html {
height:99%;
width:99%;
}

input.chatbar {
bottom:0;
width:90%;
height:5%;

outline:none;
resize: none;

border:none;
border-bottom:#000 medium solid !important;
}
```

and my HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Global Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input class="chatbar" />
</body>
</html>
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NRKpH/) is a JSFiddle of it.

I want it to float above the page and scroll with the user, like the Omegle bar. How would I do this?

Sorry, I know this is a basic question, but I can't find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NRKpH/2/ Like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position: fixed;` to the css

Also be careful about the percent heights. Check out [min and max height properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-height)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried that earlier, and when it didn't work, I removed the code. I forgot to add it back in after a few tweaks.